# Backbone / Marionette JS : navigation region, chan

Tags: marionette, init, nav, region

I'm learning backbone / marionette js and i'm using a boilerplate to do so : https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate-Lite

I have created 2 view (welcome / files) and 2 regions : mains and header.

In my headerRegion there is my navbar and I would like to handle the "active" class of my menu (template: header.html) on change or reload... but I can't figure out what is the best way to do it

I have defined a Region in my App.js :

```
App.addRegions({
        headerRegion:"header",
        mainRegion:"#main"
});
```

In my controller i create a new HeaderView on init:

```
initialize:function (options) {
        App.headerRegion.show(new HeaderView(options));
}
```

And this is my HeaderView :

```
define([ 'marionette', 'handlebars', "App", 'text!templates/header.html'],
function (Marionette, Handlebars, App, template) {
    //ItemView provides some default rendering logic
    return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template:Handlebars.compile(template),
         initialize: function (options) {
          _.bindAll();
        },
        onRender : function(options){
          $('ul.nav li', this.$el).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

});

Thanks for your help :) !

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) is to use Backbone.picky to manage which header model is the active one, and add the proper CSS class in that case. You can see the relevant header model selection here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/header/list/list_controller.js

And when the user enters the app via a direct URL (e.g. a book mark), I set the proper active header (e.g. https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/contacts_app.js)

Comment: Well thanks for your help, but this seems to be quite complicate for such a little feature :o.